# Swift MapView -> start "didSelectAnnotation" programmatically isn't the same like to tap with a finger on annotation

Tags: ios, swift, android-mapview, mkannotationview

My princip is easy: When you tap on an annotation (didSelectAnnotation) a infoscreen appears. 
When you tap on the Map the infoscreen (didDeselectAnnotation) disappears.

Now it should be possible to let the infoscreen appear, when the user tap a button, too.

So I start/call `mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView)` in my code. This works fine. But when I click on my map, it doesn't disappear. I have first to click on the annotation (didSelectAnnoation) and after that the map listen for the didDeselectAnnoation.

What kind of problem is that and how can I fix that?

I can't find anything at google but maybe I'm searching wrong. Thank you for help and sorry for bad english (I'm still learning :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [this](https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/selectAnnotation:animated:) method:

```
func selectAnnotation(_ annotation: MKAnnotation,
             animated animated: Bool)
```

It selects the specified annotation and displays a callout view for it.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help :)